# How to prevent iOS app launching whilest defining protocol handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have successfully implemented urlHandling of a self-defined protocol.

I need to prevent the app from launching when other apps try to call this url for security issues. The protocol is only needed for a callback from executed JavaScript-code, so only calls within the app are allowed.

To use the response of `UIWebView:stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString` is not an option because the JS code has to work on multiple platforms.

I thought of intercepting the call itself within my app (which would work by using `UIWebViewDelegate:shouldStartLoadWithRequest`) but I could not figure out if that is possible with WP8. (In Android this would work with `WebViewClient:shouldOverideUrlLoading`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I've found a solution that works for me. ;) It's a different approach, though.

First: you might want to check out [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge), thats a Bridge for communication in both directions implementing callbacks and everyhting you might need. But that is working with iframes... I wanted to use ajax.

I'm not implementing a protocol that my app is going to listen to. What I do now is implement a [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which will allways return `NO` for `canInitWithRequest`. I am using a unique path (like `/!anythingUnique`) to identify my JS-Calls. With that set up I can call ajax and do stuff in the Obj-C code.

1. implement NSURLProtocol.
2. register NSURLProtocol via `[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[SFJURLProtocol class]];`.
3. you will need to set a baseURL... do that by loading any page or or via `webView:loadHTMLSString`. Do that when you initialize the controller.
4. fire Requests from JavaScript
5. catch them in your `canInitWithRequest`function. You might want to do stuff in the Controller for the sake of clean code, so think of a callback mechanism or something. ;)
6. ???
7. Profit!

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol method:

```
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
```

and checking `sourceApplication`?

Comment: I am currently using this method but my problem is that my application gets started anyways. I don't want my app to start because of possible social hacking and fishing. =)

I've tried returning 'NO' but the app starts anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no standard API on iOS to have something like a "white-list" for which apps are allowed to call your custom URL scheme and open your app this way. When using this URL schemes, you can only have the whole cake, not just a small piece.

**Suggestion A:**
You could set a boolean variable in your app delegate to store if `openURL` was initiated from your app or another, in your view controller check if this variable is set to `NO` and exchange the `rootViewController` of your apps' `window` with a blank screen or an info screen telling the user that the app was not opened from a trusted source or whatever.

**Suggestion B:**
If you really don't want your app to open, you could make it crash in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`.

Just check if the `sourceApplication` is a trusted source and if not use something like `NSAssert(YES == NO, @"Bad bad boy")` to make it crash.

**B** would only be a hack and I would not consider it best practice. Try suggestion A, it is a much more user-friendly way and you should be able to achieve your goal.

Comment: Oh... that sounds too bad :( to suggestion A: I would go a step further and bind such actions to a secure token ;) or implement it like trojanfoe is suggesting. to suggestion B: that really sounds like a hack and I don't think that I will implement it that way either. Thanks for your answer anyways! :)